# LruCache not storing bitmap in kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bitmap, android-lru-cache

I am simply trying to cache bitmap into `LruCache HashMap` by doing this:

```
private lateinit var cacheStock: LruCache<String, Bitmap>
private lateinit var cacheStock: LruCache<String, Bitmap>
var maxCacheSize: Int = (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024).toInt() / 8

   //Default Max Cache Size
    var maxCacheSize: Int = MemoryUtils().getVMCacheSize() / 8

    cacheStock = object : LruCache<String, Bitmap>(maxCacheSize) {

        override fun sizeOf(key: String?, value: Bitmap): Int {
            //returns bytecount in a bitmap
            return value.getByteCount() / 1024;
        }
    }

    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder);

    var bitmapdrawable:BitmapDrawable;
    bitmapdrawable= imageView.drawable as BitmapDrawable;

    cacheStock.put("11",bitmapdrawable.bitmap);
    cacheStock.put("12",bitmapdrawable.bitmap);
    cacheStock.put("13",bitmapdrawable.bitmap);


    cacheStock.get("11");
    cacheStock.get("12");
    cacheStock.get("13");
```

But the `cacheStock` does not save key-value pairs in it. It always has size 0 even after putting a bitmap into it.I also want to know is `LruCache` a persistent memory ? 
Please suggest where I am making a mistake.

Comment: Check the value of `maxCacheSize` just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Putting a `Bitmap` into it fails when `value!!.byteCount / 1024` evaluates to zero. If you put in a large enough `Bitmap`, it will work also with the current code.

You need to make sure that `sizeOf()` never returns `0`. One easy way to do that is to work with bytes instead of kilobytes. Just remove both of your `/ 1024` divisions and the code will work.

Comment: I tried removing `/1024` from both places both, still not saving.

Comment: by the way `/1024` is there in [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/cache-bitmap#kotlin).

Comment: @AliAkram Please provide complete sample code, including the code where you add the bitmap and how you create the bitmap, and also what Android platform you run on.

Comment: Your code works for me. But you did not provide a complete example. For example, I don't have R.drawable.placeholder. And just `cacheStock.get("11")` is pointless. What do you expect should happen here? Please provide a more complete example. And avoid things like `(Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024).toInt() / 8`. Use a fixed value instead.

Comment: Try with something other than Bitamp, e.g. Integer, and make sizeOf return the value of the integer.

Comment: The point I was missing or confusing was `LruCache` is persistent memory and I was expecting it to keep bitmap even after reopening app but i got to know that its only app level memory that destroy with app life cycle.